# Using "neither ... nor" with 3 "options"

Tags: grammar

I wonder if this sentence is grammatically correct or not:

> **Neither** at your time, **nor** before, **nor** later.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103148/is-more-than-one-nor-after-a-neither-correct

Comment: That answers perfectly my question. Thank you very much @userr2684291

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage of "neither...nor....nor.." here is grammatically correct.

FYI - This construction is fairly literary/formal/archaic. Perfectly appropriate for formal writing, but would sound odd in casual conversation or even casual writing (like a blog post).

It's unclear what is meant by "at your time".

Comment: Thank you. By *at your time" I mean *at your era* ... *at the period of time you lived in*